# Aggregate method and lambda function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` and would like to get the `ID` list for each class:

```
import pandas as pd
list1 = [[1, ('A', 'B', 'C')], [2, ('M', 'E', 'F')], [3, ('H', 'A', 'D')], [4, ('H', 'A', 'D')]]    
df = pd.DataFrame(list1, columns=['ID', 'Class'])
```

`df` looks like

```
ID    Class
1     (A, B, C) 
2     (M, E, F) 
3     (H, A, D) 
4     (H, A, D)
```

The desired output is:

```
Class        ID 
(A, B, C)    [1]
(M, E, F)    [2] 
(H, A, D)    [3, 4]
```

I tried to use the code below, but it is not working. Thanks.

```
df.groupby('Class')['ID'].aggregate(lambda x: list(x))
```

Comment: `lambda x: list(x)` is equivalent to `list`, but with more runtime overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lot of solutions here one:

```
df = df.groupby('Class')['ID'].apply(list).reset_index()

       Class      ID
0  (A, B, C)     [1]
1  (H, A, D)  [3, 4]
2  (M, E, F)     [2]
```

Answer (score 3):

You should using

```
df.groupby('Class').ID.agg(list).reset_index()
Out[473]: 
       Class      ID
0  (A, B, C)     [1]
1  (H, A, D)  [3, 4]
2  (M, E, F)     [2]
```

To fix your code

```
df.groupby('Class')['ID'].aggregate(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

Comment: Hi Wenben, I got some error message. When I run df.groupby('Class').ID.agg(list).reset_index(), it says TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable.

Comment: When I run df.groupby('Class')['ID'].aggregate(lambda x: x.tolist()), it says ValueError: Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.

Comment: @SteveP make sure that is tuple or list? Incolumn class

Comment: Hi Wen-Ben, column Class such as (A, B, C) is a tuple.

Comment: @SteveP if it is same like what you show to us , my query should work

Comment: I tried the solution from Frenchy, it works. I am using python 3.6, could that be the issue?  thanks.

Comment: @SteveP what is your pandas version ?

Comment: @SteveP I mean pandas .

Comment: pd.__version__
Out[3]: '0.19.2'

Comment: @SteveP update your pandas , the issue is fixed in the current version .